# Mail servers complain that there's no valid MX record but there is

Tags: mx-record, gmail

We have a domain that uses gmail for its mail exchange but some mail servers are bouncing our emails with the following message:

> The error that the other server returned was:
>   550 The email sent from 209.85.192.51 by admin@wearemobedia.com was rejected by 
>   the receiving server as the senders domain does not have a valid A and/or MX 
>   record. Please go to http://www.emailbouncing.info for more information.

I've checked the mx records and A records for the domain in question and they seem fine and i've compared them with our old domain which definitely works and they seem to be identical but googles mx checking tool flags up an issue with the new domain but not the old one so I'm at a bit of a loss.

What is causing some mail servers to complain about the mx records on wearemobedia.com but not mobedia.co.uk when they seem to be identical?

Comment: You have non-Authoritative nameservers listed, remove these first

Comment: Thanks for posting your actual domain, otherwise it would have been impossible to answer your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nameservers are badly misconfigured. I ran your zone through [the test engine at DNSCheck](http://dnscheck.iis.se/?time=1455794965&id=5474031&view=basic&test=standard), and got the following result:

> No name servers could be found at the child. This usually means that the child is not configured to answer queries about the zone.

Some DNS clients will still find the MX record for you, but it's really not reliable, and Google's mailservers obviously require an actual working nameserver in order to look up your MX.